# Bootstrap modal fire but no display

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I trying to use bootstrap modal, event `'show'` is fired but I can't see it on screen.
home.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Log...");

    $(document).on('click', '#btnSignIn', function(){
        console.log("Starting modal..");
        $('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
            alert("Modal show..");
        }).modal('show');
    });
});
```

modal in home.jsp

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h1>AKA</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

alert is fired but then, no modal is shown. Anybody can help me? Please

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your javascript console?

Comment: No error messages, buddy! That's why I don't know what happened! I debug js by Chrome but find nothing!

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/u1b79cdL/, I notice that it doesn't work if I switch from Bootstrap 2.3 to 3.0 though. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I use 3.0 of course!

Comment: I know! I've tried on jsfiddle already! That's why I wonder why it doesn't work in eclipse

Comment: it doesn't work too, @adamdehaven

Comment: provide a demo that replicates problem. Could be a css conflict which you can easily inspect within browser developer tools console

Comment: css conflict is impossible, I use bootstrap only without custom css!

Comment: Your modal's DOM structure is wrong. [Run Bootlint on your page](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint#in-the-browser), it'll point out the problem.

Comment: See [the official migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/#notes), it mentions the modal changes for v2->v3.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Bootstrap 3, you need to remove the hide class from your modal html:

Change This:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
```

To this:

```
  <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
```